# Does Movies and TV covers film-making questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm launching a [Film Making](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47970/film-making) proposal, but if this kind of questions are on-topic in Movies and Tv, I'd like to remove it. Is it?

Comment: no..............

Comment: Talking with some of the mods on AVP, it seems that most of the questions on your proposal, aside from the one asking about most Film Making Uni, are **On-Topic** for AVP.

Comment: Questions about screenwriting - TV or film - can be asked on [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, we do not accept questions about Film Making as a profession but as an analysis of a work (ex: What significance is there for the LotR movies to be filmed in New Zealand).

For technical aspects of professional film making, we have been directing users to [AVP.SE](http://avp.stackexchange.com), as @DForck42 said.

If you have more specific questions, I would ask on [their meta](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com) and read their [FAQ](https://video.stackexchange.com/faq) to see if your ideas will be accepted there.

Answer (score 2):

Your proposal seems to be a duplicate of an already existing site: https://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: AVP is almost purely about technical aspects of handling sound and picture. Filmmaking has tons of other potential questions, like directing, light department, art department, production, etc.